# In the environment of Android 13, how can I obtain Bluetooth transmission data through services supported by Termux? Can anyone help this?

Tags: javascript

- OS:Android 13
- wanted:Termux get Bluetooth transmission data
- try and faild: I have already tried all the Bluetooth-supported nodes (Classic and BLE) on Node-RED

If it's not through Node-RED. At the very least, I would like to find the corresponding solution using Termux.It's also friendly to use node.js.